# How to add pre and post hooks in webpack watch mode when an update event happens?

Tags: webpack

For example, after I execute `webpack --watch` and everytime an update event `E` happens, I want:

before `E`: remove some files in some folder
after `E`: scan file names in some folder and write them to some files in some format.

All in all, execute some node code before and after `E` happens. Provided this config file.

```
module.exports = {

    output: {
        path: 'dist',
        publicPath: '/static/', 
        filename:  "bundle.[hash].js", 
    },

    module: {                
        loaders: [
            { 
                test: /\.css$/, 
                loaders: ["style", "css"],
            }, 
        ], 
    },
};
```

Answer (score 6):

I can't believe I find this. It's exactly what I want. Good luck.

```
var ProgressHook = new webpack.ProgressPlugin(function(percentage, msg) {
    if (percentage==0){
        // pre-hook code (before webpack compiles )
    } else if (percentage==1){
        // post-hook code (after webpack compiles )  
    } 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-shell-plugin

```
This plugin allows you to run any shell commands before or after webpack builds. This will work for both webpack and webpack-dev-server.
```